# Unable to extract recordId from the lightning web component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I tried to get record id from the custom object "Categories__c" unfortunately it is not working. When I try the same with the custom recordId, it works. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?.

Here are my following codes:
Categories.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="spread" multiple-rows>
            <lightning-record-view-form record-id= {recordId} object-api-name="Categories__c">
                <p style="color:blue;">Categories</p>
                <div class="slds-box slds-theme\_default">
            <lightning-layout-item size= 6 >
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Consultant_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Developer_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Senior_Developer_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Senior_Consultant_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Personal_Manager_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
           </lightning-layout-item>
           </div>
            </lightning-record-view-form>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Categories.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import CONSULTANT from '@salesforce/schema/Categories__c.Consultant_Summary__c';
import DEVELOPER from '@salesforce/schema/Categories__c.Developer_Summary__c';
import SENIOR_CONSULTANT from '@salesforce/schema/Categories__c.Senior_Consultant_Summary__c';
import SENIOR_DEVELOPER from '@salesforce/schema/Categories__c.Senior_Developer_Summary__c';
import PERSONAL_MANAGER from '@salesforce/schema/Categories__c.Personal_Manager_Summary__c';
import getcat from '@salesforce/apex/CategoriesController.getcat';

const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'Consultant (No of Days Estimated)', fieldName: CONSULTANT.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Developer (No of Days Estimated)', fieldName: DEVELOPER.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Senior Consultant (No of Days Estimated)', fieldName: SENIOR_CONSULTANT.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Senior Developer (No of Days Estimated)', fieldName: SENIOR_DEVELOPER.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Personal Manager (No of Days Estimated)', fieldName: PERSONAL_MANAGER.fieldApiName, type: 'number' }
];
export default class Categories extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    columns = COLUMNS;
    @wire(getcat)
    cats;
}
```

Categories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Here is the output if I give an actual record id instead of the keyword,
[image: with manual record id]

Here is the output when I actually use the keyword "recordId".
[image]

Comment: there is a "space" after your property declaration in the template, make sure that there is none Ex. record-id={prop}

Comment: It's still not working.

Comment: recordId will work on record pages, I dont think it works locally

Comment: Yes, it works now. Can you make type it as an answer so that I can accept your answer?.

Comment: sure, done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recordId does not work Locally, it will only work on record pages as documented:

[Make a Component Aware of Its Record Context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context)

> **IMPORTANT** The recordId is set only when you place or invoke the
> component in an explicit record context. In all other cases, the
> recordId isn’t set, and your component can’t depend on it.